# Is there a possibility to deactivate swipe navigation on mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, vue.js, mobile-browser

I am building a VueJS form, which has multiple steps and a back button, to go to the previous step. All steps are managed in a parent component, so the URL / router history does not change with the steps.

So when a user swipes over the edge of their phone the browser navigates to the previous page on the browser history. I want to change this behaviour, so the swipe gesture has the same function as the back button on my form (navigate between form steps, not pages) or is deactivated completely.

I have already tried to

- set `touch-action: none` on the body and html
- set `overscroll-behaviour: none` on the body and html
- call `preventDefault()` on `touchstart` and `touchmove`

However, the swipe behaviour does not seem to be influenced by the web app. Is there any way to prevent the navigation?

I am currently testing on Safari iOS on the xCode simulator, but the desired behaviour would have to work both on iOS and Android.

Comment: The reason this is failing in Safari is that the `touchstart` event is a `passive` listener. You must specify the 3rd option as `false` otherwise `preventDefault()` has no impact. You can verify this by looking in the console and seeing a `warning` message being generated that indicates exactly what I'm saying. So `window.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => e.preventDefault(), { passive: false})` should rectify your issue. Of course, this only applies to `wheel, mousewheel, touchstart and touchmove` events in Safari.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thank you so much! It works. Can you post this as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the answer, look at the comment from @Ohgowhy

The event listener needed `{ passive: false }` passed as option. This worked on every major mobile browser but Firefox on Android